# iptables block 1 ip, nat

Tags: iptables

I have a server with 2 interfaces. a small netework connects to eth0 and gets out to internet on eth1.
To allow 1 ip to nat I use

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -s 192.168.0.23 -j SNAT --to-source=23.x.x.x
```

I would like to add a rule that allow a single ip do nat and block the others already existing in iptables(without deleting them)

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o OUT_IF \! -s ip_sursa -j SNAT --to-source=x3.xxx.1xx.1xx -j DROP
```

would work?

Or, to allow only 1 ip to pass over eth0 to eth1 and do nat.

Answer (score 3):

It is not recommended to use `DROP` in the NAT table. It is better to do this the filter table if you want to deny the access to these IP addresses.

Otherwise, you can use a different rule to NAT these IPs to a different public IP.

**Update**

Here are the rules you need to allow only one IP (192.168.0.100)

```
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -s 192.168.0.100 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -s 192.168.0.100 -j SNAT --to-source=23.x.x.x
```

Comment: so...how can I do it? How to allow only 1 ip pass from eth0 to eth1?

Comment: You can use `iptables -A FORWARD -o OUT_IF -s IP_range -j DROP`.

Comment: the ip i want to allow is 192.168.0.100. I want to block all the others.How to give the range from 0-99 and 101-254(with 192.168.0.0/24 i will block all class). can i give IP_range=192.168.0.1-192.168.0.99 and 192.168.0.101-192.168.0.254 and make 2 rules?

Comment: "iptables -A FORWARD -o OUT_IF -s IP_range -j DROP" without "-t nat"?I need nat

Comment: iptables -A FORWARD -o OUT_IF -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.0-192.168.1.99 -j DROP             and iptables -A FORWARD -o OUT_IF -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.101-192.168.1.254 -j DROP would work?

Comment: ok.thx Khaled, i will try it...